# How to implement a Haskell extension?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I have several ideas of extensions for Haskell, that can be implemented by translating extended language to normal one (the extensions will provide some pragmas and keywords).
What is the better way to implement them? It should be build over GHC.

One of ideas is to add keyword for "functional classes", the classes, that will be automatically defined by functions.
For example, with this hypothetical extension, standard Num class can be defined like this:

```
class (funclass(+) a,funclass(-) a, ...) => Num a
```

Comment: While this is an interesting idea, thinking about how it would actually be used reminds me horribly of C++' ad-hoc overloading – perhaps with not quite so severe duck-typing errors, but you'd still need to be very careful with the instances' signatures, which the standard Haskell class instances nicely take off you. And since you can make classes arbitrarily fine-grained I don't see any real advantage, not even in avoiding boilerplate.

Comment: @leftaroundabout This idea can be useful to automatically create most generalized modules. For this example, while we can define complex numbers, as an instance of Num, we can't define matrices like that, for obvious reasons. But using of (+) and (-) for them and functions, builded upon them is still can be useful. With this extension, we can define matrices, as an instances of (+) and (-).

Comment: There's perfectly fine [classes for more general additive groups / vector spaces](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space). `Num` as a name is quite descriptive and limiting `(+)` and `(-)` to such actual _numbers_, but requiring `(^+^)` to be used for matrices etc. seems not a bad tradeoff to me, since it simplifies the Prelude with no influence on many simpler Haskell projects, and little bothers those project that need vector spaces etc.. Incidentally, you _can_ even make a `Num` instance for matrices, though `abs` and `signum` are a bit weird.

Comment: And, of course, there's the [numeric Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude), which splits up the numeric classes as finely as possible, so `(+)` actually works for any group, etc..

Comment: @leftaroundabout off-course, we can simply redefine something, to make it generalizable, but this hypothetical extension will let to build something as generalizable, as possible.

Comment: "As generalisable as possible" isn't really well-defined. What you're trying to allow people to do isn't so much generalising as "arbitrarising": anybody may reuse the _symbol_ `+` anywhere they want. But really, what makes Haskell's type classes so powerful and general is that they are a place to _bundle_ multiple operations with particular _laws_, like the monad laws (for `Num` those would be the [ring axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_axioms), though it's not exactly well-specified). Only that makes it possible to use the operators in a really general and safe manner.

Answer (score 4):

As I see it, there are three ways you might do this:

1. Implement a preprocessor which reads extended Haskell source code, translates it into normal Haskell, and saves that back to disk. You can then compile the translated Haskell code as normal.
2. Implement some code with Template Haskell that will do the translation for you. (In particular, some kind of quasi-quoter may be appropriate.)
3. Modify GHC itself. (This obviously requires recompiling GHC, and then checking you haven't accidentally broken any existing functionality.) I would suggest that this is probably a hell of a lot of work.

I was about to mention that you could write a GHC plugin - however, such plugins do *not* allow you to define new syntax. (Though they *do* allow you to define new compiler pragmas, which would then be translated into normal Haskell.) If you can get this approach to work, it means you get to avoid recompiling GHC. You would just be writing a small, self-contained plugin. But Template Haskell will probably do the job more easily.

As to whether your proposed extension is a good idea... I don't think it is, but you are of course welcome to experiment with using it.

Comment: About 1-st way. It's an easy one, but I need at least some correct parser for Haskell (native parser). I googled "haskell parser", but found not the thing I need (parsec, and parsers, that can be used in Haskell).

Comment: @AnonImous [**haskell-src-exts**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts) should serve you well. Also FYI you can [search thru Hackage directly](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=lexer).

Answer (score 2):

> I have several ideas of extensions for Haskell, that can be implemented by translating extended language to normal one.

SugarHaskell is built for this. It is part of the [SugarJ](http://sugarj.org/) project for extensible languages. Also see the [Haskell symposium paper](http://sugarj.org/sugarhaskell.pdf) and [package on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sugarhaskell).

Potential **strong points** about SugarHaskell: It comes with an extensible grammar that supports modular specification of layout constraints, so you can easily define syntax that behaves like do notation. It comes with an Eclipse plugin that is aware of the syntax extensions, so you get extensible syntax highlighting. Other features of the Eclipse plugin are also extensible (code completion, error reporting, outline view, ...).

Potential **weak points** about SugarHaskell: It is implemented in Java (glue code and Eclipse plugin), SDF (grammar) and Stratego (desugarings). The hackage package contains mostly a bunch of Java code. That's not necessarily a weak point, but maybe you would prefer to use Haskell to specify your desugarings instead of Stratego. No integration in other editors beside Eclipse. The Eclipse plugin is nicely extensible, but the basic support for Haskell is weak, so it is currently not really usable for large Haskell projects.

Given potential weak points, SugarHaskell is not suited for production use today, but it might be useful for experimentation and prototyping of language extensions.